Oauth2.0 auth server and resource server in same app and 3rd party client
I want to make the auth server and the resource serve in same app. I know that there are existing topics about this: but i cannot make it to work.
Previously, I managed to set up a scenario where my auth server, resource server, and client were separate applications, each configured with the necessary dependencies (e.g., spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server for the resource server, and similar for the client and auth server).
But now I want to make the authserver and resource server in same app, and client who wont have any oauth dependencies or properties...
My auth-server looks like this:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling(
            (exceptions) -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    http.cors(customizer -> customizer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource));
    return http.build();

}

@Bean
@Order(2)
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().roles("user").username("vlatko").password("pw")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
}

@Bean
RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).clientId("oidc-client")
            .clientSecret("{noop}secret").clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client")
            .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/").scope(OidcScopes.OPENID).scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
            .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build()).build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
}
@Bean
AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
}
}

Additionally, I've added a simple controller and service to serve as the resource:
@RestController
public class ResourceController {

private final ResourceService service;

ResourceController(ResourceService service) {
    this.service = service;
}

@GetMapping("/hello")
Map<String, String> hello() {
    return service.sayHello();
}
}

@Service
public class ResourceService {

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_user.read')")
public Map<String, String> sayHello() {
    var jwt = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return Map.of("message", "Hello " + jwt.getSubject());
}
}

Now, let's assume we want to call this endpoint from some app that isn't configured for OAuth 2.0. I've created a simple app to call this endpoint but received a 401 Unauthorized response. I understand that I likely need to request an authorization code and then an access token from the auth server, but I'm unsure how to manage this from the client side.
So, my questions are:

Is it possible to integrate the auth server and resource server in the same Spring Boot application while keeping the client separate and without OAuth configurations?
Is my auth server configuration correct for this scenario?
How should I manage OAuth 2.0 interactions on the client side to access protected resources?

Any examples or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
BTW: I have tested my auth server with: https://oauthdebugger.com/ and I receive success and authorization code, but after sending a request to:
http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token i receive 401
